# Drawing a circle in android with opengl-es results in a square

Tags: android, opengl-es, trigonometry, geometry

I am trying to draw a circle in opengl-es using the following code. It creates a number of points around a circle. If I print out the values in the vertex array it can be seen that they form points around a circle.

```
// Create verticies for a circle

points=40;
vertices = new float[(points+1)*3];

//CENTER OF CIRCLE
vertices[0]=0.0f;
vertices[1]=0.0f;
vertices[2]=0.0f;

for (int i = 3; i<(points+1)*3; i+=3){
    double rad = deg2rad(i*360/points);
    vertices[i] = (float) (Math.cos(rad));
    vertices[i+1] = (float) (Math.sin(rad));
    vertices[i+2] = 0;
}

// vertexBuffer is filled with verticies
```

And the calls to opengl in my drawing function:

```
// IN MY DRAWING FUNCTION:
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
gl.glScalef(size, size, 1.0f);
gl.glColor4f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 1.0f); 
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points/2);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

However I never get a circle drawn to the screen, only ever a square. I am very confused, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: For others reading this question, they should consider that a way to debug this might be to reduce the number of iterations in the loop (even to one iteration) and see what happens and how it goes wrong with more and more iterations.

Answer (score 2):

one thing that looks wrong is the calculation of `rad`.  Try modifying it to something like:

```
double rad = deg2rad(i*360/(points*3));
```

You need to divide it by `points*3` because the `i` counter is getting incremented by 3 on each iteration.  You should print out the value of `rad` on each iteration and verify that you're getting values incrementing between 0 and 2 * PI

EDIT: you may also need to change the **direction** of the circle (i'm not sure at the top of my head).  but if the above doesn't render anything, try reversing it:

```
double rad = deg2rad(360.0 - i*360/(points*3));
```

Also, it looks like you're only rendering half the points in the `glDrawArrays` call.

Comment: All good points, but no of which explain why it's drawing a square :(

Comment: does it *still* draw a square after these changes?  is it a perfect square or jaggy edges?

Answer (score 2):

```
//...vertex and index buffers...

int VERTICES=180; // more than needed  // changed variable name 
float coords[] = new float[VERTICES * 3];
float theta = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < VERTICES * 3; i += 3) {
  coords[i + 0] = (float) Math.cos(theta);
  coords[i + 1] = (float) Math.sin(theta);
  coords[i + 2] = 0;
  vertexBuffer.put(coords[i + 0]);
  vertexBuffer.put(coords[i + 1]);
  vertexBuffer.put(coords[i + 2]);
  theta += Math.PI / 90;
}

// ....set buffer positions to zero...

protected void draw(GL10 gl) {
  gl.glColor4f(0, 0, 1, 0.5f);
  gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
  gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, VERTICES,
    GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
    }
}
```

Easy breezy.